# Why image is not displayed into list view?

Tags: android

this is the code 
image is not displayed into list view how can i solve this problem?I set uri value into bitmap.so what is the problem?changed the array and error is solved bt still image is not displayed into list view.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    Context context;

    ArrayList prgmName;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    //bitmap=getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");

    public static String [] prgmNameList={"Let Us C","c++","JAVA","Jsp","Microsoft .Net","Android","PHP","Jquery","JavaScript"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bitmap=getBitmapFromUrl("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg");
        context=this;
        Bitmap  [] prgmImages ={bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap,bitmap};
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            URL url =new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybiBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return mybiBitmap;


         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
         }


    }

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    String [] result;
    Context context;
 Bitmap[] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, Bitmap[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;        
             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
//         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
//         holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[position]);         
             if(result != null && result.length > position)
             { 
               holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
             }

             if(imageId != null && imageId.length > 0)
             {
                holder.img.setImageBitmap(imageId[0]); 
             }

             rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });  
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=" Your Theaters..." />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml layout list_item file also.

Comment: Check log whether you are getting any error

Comment: Did you add "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
" permission in manifest?

Comment: You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter when the bitmap is already downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens because before bitmaps get loaded and saved to your array, you call adapter. Downloading images takes some time and your adapter is not waiting for them. See this example, it is using image loader: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: But in this example url contain xml file but in my example url not contain xml file so how can i parse this?my url is,http://reeldealsantikosapi.staging2.perpetuating.com/ReelDealServices.svc/POS/GetShowTimesForTheater3?TheaterId=7&CurrentDate=06/18/2014&Latitude=23.0111802&Longitude=72.5066194

Comment: You don't need parsing. Just put in your getView of adapter: imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://content6.flixster.com/movie/11/17/75/11177548_pro.jpg", thumb_image);

Comment: how can i parse my url? I got null pointer exception because this url has no node name?i am parsing this url because i want name of movie with image of movie,how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in the log ?

When calling `getBitmapFromUrl` from `onCreate`, you are downloading the bitmap on the main thread, [which is prohibited if your application is targeting Honeycomb or later](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). In your case it will fail silently because you are catching the exception but you will get a null result.

As loading images from network is very common, there are a lot of library that handle this (and a lot more like caching) for you, e.g. [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
or [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)